# Looking for help to let the bot move between activities by listening to user input

Tags: android, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I want to make a voice-text bot using DialogFlow to return an Activity.

The bot works well in terms of voice-text mode .. but I want the bot to answer the user by an Activity as the user ask him !

Like an example : I want "Messi goals in world cup 2018". 
Result will be the activity that i will add in Android Studio and that will include Messi pictures with his goals and so on ..

my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
    ImageButton btnSpeak;
    TextView txtSpeechInput, outputText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnSpeak = findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        txtSpeechInput = findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput);
        outputText = findViewById(R.id.outputTex);
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                promptSpeechInput();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Showing google speech input dialog
     */
    private void promptSpeechInput() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        // intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                "Say Something");
        try {
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "orry! Your device doesn\\'t support speech input",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Receiving speech input
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                    ArrayList<String> result = data
                            .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                    String userQuery = result.get(0);
                    txtSpeechInput.setText(userQuery);
                    RetrieveFeedTask task=new RetrieveFeedTask();
                    task.execute(userQuery);
                }
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    // Create GetText Metod

    public String GetText(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        String text = "";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        // Send data
        try {
            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL("my url");

            // Send POST data request

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer client access token code");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            //Create JSONObject here
            JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray queryArray = new JSONArray();
            queryArray.put(query);
            jsonParam.put("query", queryArray);
            //jsonParam.put("name", "order a medium pizza");
            jsonParam.put("lang", "en");
            jsonParam.put("sessionId", "1234567890");

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            Log.d("karma", "after conversion is " + jsonParam.toString());
            wr.write(jsonParam.toString());
            wr.flush();
            Log.d("karma", "json is " + jsonParam);

            // Get the server response

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;


            // Read Server Response
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            text = sb.toString();

            JSONObject object1 = new JSONObject(text);
            JSONObject object = object1.getJSONObject("result");
            JSONObject fulfillment = null;
            String speech = null;
            //if (object.has("fulfillment")) {
            fulfillment = object.getJSONObject("fulfillment");
            //if (fulfillment.has("speech")) {
            speech = fulfillment.optString("speech");
            //                }
            //             }


            Log.d("karma ", "response is " + text);
            return speech;

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("karma", "exception at last " + ex);
        } finally {
            try {

                reader.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        return null;}

        class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... voids) {
                String s = null;
                try {

                    s = GetText(voids[0]);


                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("karma", "Exception occurred " + e);
                }

                return s;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                outputText.setText(s);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I prefer to make one page but many fragment in this case so you can add the bot at the root activity, the other fragments should use this bot internally

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Android library](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client) for Dialogflow and based on the response coming switch between different Activities or Fragments. It would be better to have one central activity for Dialogflow communication and switch between fragments or views.